# Firebase Hosting Can't Add Domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

When I try to add a custom domain to Firebase Hosting, I encounter this error. Nothing happens when I click Continue.

Upon clicking continue, it loads for a few seconds, and then the same screen persists.

[image: 1]

When I checked the console, HTTP requests are responded with 503 Service Unable.

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

While we did make some changes to our custom domain provisioning this week, it seems that you're hitting another problem.

Is any part of this on a Google Workspace account by any chance? If that is the case, your domain may not allow the search console. You'll want to reach out to their GSuite organization admin/owner to enable the Search Console. See [Turn Google Search Console on or off for users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6237949) for complete instructions.